# About the meaning of "unless you should get ahead of him" in a particular context

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is the text and the context:

> [1905-08-29, A. I. Root, “Letter to the Wright brothers”](https://www.loc.gov/resource/mwright.03200/?sp=23)
>
> Dear Sirs:-
>   Well friends I suppose you will excuse your old friend, A. I. Root, if he does get a little anxious. You see Knabenshue is forging ahead so I have been wondering if he would not begin to use a lighter balloon, a still lighter, and after a while no balloon at all **unless you folks should get ahead of him** in some way. … As ever, A. I. Root.

I have to explain what was in Root's mind when he wrote the letter.
This is my "translation":

*In August 1905, A. I. Root feared that, if Knabenshue succeed in flying without a balloon and the Wright brothers made no progress, Knabenshue would get ahead of them.*

I do not get quite well the meaning of "unless you folks should get ahead of him". Is it equivalent to "if you folks do not get ahead of him"?

**UPDATE**

There are three clauses of interest:

1) I have been wondering 
2) if he would not begin to use ...
3) unless you folks should get ahead of him ...

I do not even know how to relate them to each other.
It is clear that (2) is connected to (1) but about (3) I am unsure. Is it linked to (1) or to (2)?

Comment: I think your paraphrase indicates your hunch about what this means is a correct one.

Comment: There is a small problem. A. I. Root had already seen Wilbur Wright performing a spectacular flight, without a balloon, on Sep. 20, 1904. So, even if Knabenshue had succeeded in flying without a baloon he would not have got ahead of the two brothers. It is impossible to get ahead of an inventor who first did something.

Comment: As you can see from the sans-serif font, the date was not typed onto the letter. It is an inked stamp. Are you certain that stamp is original (and accurate)? Could the year chunk have rolled forward accidentally? Each of those date-chunks was on a separate rubber band. MONTH DAY YEAR. You would have to find other correspondence from August 1905 and see if the year stamp was mistakenly set to 1905 instead of 1904 on any of them, judging from internal or external evidence.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1838&bih=957&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=vintage+redi-mark+inked+stamp&oq=vintage+redi-mark+inked+stamp&gs_l=img.3..35i39k1.16315.19679.0.26967.16.14.2.0.0.0.122.1047.12j2.14.0....0...1.1.64.img..0.13.917.sflpfyJtXqk#imgrc=MzuAPRlLB-OsrM%3A

Comment: The date is correct. There are subtle elements in the letter that show it was written in 1905.